# mysqli::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

I can't connect to my server. Here are the mistakes it gives me:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\PHP-Project\logic\db_connection.php on line 3
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet.
>   PID=8632 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\PHP-Project\logic\db_connection.php on
>   line 3
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone
>   away in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\PHP-Project\logic\db_connection.php on
>   line 3
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\PHP-Project\logic\db_connection.php on line 3

This is my connection file:

```
define("HOST", "localhost:81");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_NAME", "bulitfactory_person_cv");

$db_connection = new mysqli(HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if ($db_connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed. ".$db_connection->connect_error);
}
```

Please, help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL server has gone away and Error while reading greeting packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140547/mysql-server-has-gone-away-and-error-while-reading-greeting-packet)

Comment: Is your mysql really running on port 81? The default is 3306. Try removing the port if it is 3306, or add it in separately as the 5th parameter if it's not 3306.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: You can't specify a host in the format `host:port` - the port is a separate parameter.

Comment: Nothing happens again...

Comment: "Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=8632 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\PHP-Project\logic\db_connection.php on line 3" sounds to me there is een connection mismatch... maybe you are using a to old php version to connect to the newer mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

try it to increase max_allowed_packet and restart the server

Answer (score 0):

Add log_warnings=2 within [mysqld]section to your .ini/.cfg file, shutdown restart mysql and you should have maximum connection failure information in your error.log.